# How do I search Android Market based on two-word Developer Name?

Tags: android, search, google-play

(Question also posted here: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Android+Market/thread?tid=68dc1f694537c7dc&hl=en )

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html
recommends searching for apps by Developer Name using the URL:
market://search?q=pub:

I can't get this to work for two word names. For instance, if I want to search for all of Google's apps on the Market, I would search for 'Google Inc.' since if you look at Google Earth, Google Sky Map, etc. those are all published by 'Google Inc.'

I've tried the following:
market://search?q=pub:Google%2BInc%2E 
(equivalent of: Google+Inc.)

market://search?q=pub:Google%20Inc%2E 
(equivalent of: Google Inc.)

market://search?q=pub:Google Inc. 
(equivalent of: Google Inc.)

market://search?q=pub:Google+Inc.
(equivalent of: Google+Inc.)

but none work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that the magic sauce is a pair of quote marks.
Final solution:
`market://search?q=pub:"Google Inc."`

Comment: I find it amazing that after all this time the developer guide webpage still hasn't been updated to fix this mistake/typo. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: This same bug affects the Google Play Store. (I found it hard to search for this page because I kept searching for Play Store instead of Android Market.)

Comment: As seen on [this official page](http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html#OpeningPublisher "Linking to your products | Android Developers"), you can now search using `search?q=pub:Google Inc.` _(without the quotes)_

Answer (score 0):

If you use it inside a **Uri.parse** quotes won't work

```
market://search?q=pub:"Google Inc." // not working
```

you need to encode the quotes

```
market://search?q=pub:%22Google Inc.%22 // working
```